# Acoustic echo cancellation with WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, aec

I've used WebRTC's AEC module to do echo cancellation,now I encounter a question,that when I do point to point communication,if there are no one to talk in a period of time,and one point to talk again,at this time,the echo will appear,if there are always have people to talk, the echo cancellation effect is very good,I want to know,why it will have echo after no one to talk over a period of time.

Thank for any reply!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the confidence the algorithm gives to its convergence results are automatically reduced after a period of no-echo.